# How does ON DELETE CASCADE relate to JSON?

Tags: foreign-key, constraint, delete, json

For relational databases, there is the notion of `ON DELETE CASCADE`. When working with JSON, how do these two concepts relate? Is `ON DELETE CASCADE` supported for JSON?

Can you give an example of a JSON-DB which supports `ON DELETE CASCADE` or allows some work around for that?

Comment: Which "JSON DB" are you talking about? since when do they support foreign keys?

Comment: Thanks! You say "There is no JSON-DB which supports foreign keys", thus I can completely forget about "ON DELETE CASCADE". But is there some DB which offers a work around like programming a function which gets executed if the primary key is deleted and then deletes all connected rows in other tables?

Comment: I didn't say there is none. I asked since when they do support FKs - after all they are supposed to be "schema less" which makes the use of FKs essentially impossible

Comment: Okay, I updated my question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused here,

- JSON is a data-interchange format, in PostgreSQL we provide `json` and `jsonb` as formats with advantages like validation and indexing that help you work with this format.
- `ON DELETE CASCADE` is a clause that tells a referring table what to do when the table that it refers to lose the row it's referencing.

You **can** mix the two concepts, but you **should never do this**

```
CREATE TABLE tfoo ( qux jsonb PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE tbar ( qux jsonb REFERENCES tfoo );
CREATE TABLE tbaz ( qux jsonb REFERENCES tfoo ON DELETE CASCADE );
```

Now we can insert some test data in `tfoo`,

```
INSERT INTO tfoo (qux) VALUES ( '{"id":42}' );
INSERT INTO tfoo (qux) VALUES ( '{"id":7}' );
```

And you'll get a reject if you try to insert into `tbar` or `tbaz` anything but the above,

```
-- Rejection
INSERT INTO tbar (qux) VALUES ( '{"id":2}' );
ERROR:  insert or update on table "tbar" violates foreign key constraint "tbar_qux_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (qux)=({"id": 2}) is not present in table "tfoo".
```

This is a really bad idea though for many reasons. We can see here that these work though,

```
INSERT INTO tbar (qux) VALUES ( '{"id":42}' );   -- ON DELETE REJECT
INSERT INTO tbaz (qux) VALUES ( '{"id":7}' );    -- ON DELETE CASCADE
```

And moreover, we can see the effects -- `{"id":7}` is in `tbaz` which has the `ON DELETE CASCADE`

```
DELETE FROM tfoo WHERE qux = '{"id":7}';
```

And, this fails as `{"id":42}` is in `tbar` and it doesn't know what to do if you remove that entry from `tfoo` so it rejects the operation.

```
DELETE FROM tfoo WHERE qux = '{"id":42}';
ERROR:  update or delete on table "tfoo" violates foreign key constraint "tbar_qux_fkey" on table "tbar"                                              
DETAIL:  Key (qux)=({"id": 42}) is still referenced from table "tbar".
```

## Clarification

So you can see you can have `ON DELETE CASCADE` on any type that can be put on a `UNIQUE` index (`PRIMARY KEY` is a special `UNIQUE NOT NULL` index). This means, you can mix these two concepts, as we did above. **But you should never do that, and I've never seen it done in practice**. Generally, you put `FOREIGN KEYS` on `int` or `text`,

```
CREATE TABLE tfoo (
  id_foo int     PRIMARY KEY
    GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,

  qux    jsonb
);
CREATE TABLE tbar ( id_foo REFERENCES tfoo, qux jsonb );
CREATE TABLE tbaz ( id_foo REFERENCES tfoo ON DELETE CASCADE, qux jsonb );
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Evan's explanation how it should not be done, here is why it should not be done, referring to `CouchDB`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951030/does-couchdb-supports-referential-integrity

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197449/how-do-i-dry-up-my-couchdb-views